# While loop is not terminating when it hits the condition

Tags: python, while-loop

My while loop is not terminating after the condition becomes true. I'm checking for whitespace in the list. If the whitespace equals 1, it should terminate from the while loop.

```
config_index = 0
push_configs = ['  dns-server 8.8.8.8 ', ' ip dhcp pool WIRELESS', '  network 10.99.99.0 255.255.255.0', '  default-router 10.99.99.1 ', '  dns-server 8.8.8.8 ', '  ip dhcp pool HUMAN_RESOURCE ', '   network 10.88.88.0 255.255.255.0', '   default-router 10.88.88.1 ', '   dns-server 8.8.8.8 ']

whitespace = len(push_configs[config_index]) - len(push_configs[config_index].lstrip())
while(whitespace != 1):
    print whitespace
    push_configs.pop(config_index)
    config_index = config_index + 1
    whitespace = len(push_configs[config_index]) - len(push_configs[config_index].lstrip())
    print whitespace
```

Results in

```
2
'  dns-server 8.8.8.8 '
2
2
'  network 10.99.99.0 255.255.255.0'
2
2
'  dns-server 8.8.8.8 '
3
3
'   network 10.88.88.0 255.255.255.0'
3
3
'   dns-server 8.8.8.8 '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> push_configs
[' ip dhcp pool WIRELESS', '  default-router 10.99.99.1 ', '  ip dhcp pool HUMAN_RESOURCE ', '   default-router 10.88.88.1 ']
```

As you can see, it continues through the entire list until it hits a "list index out of range". Given the list `push_configs`, the desired result would be to terminate from the while loop once it gets to the second element.

Comment: Your condition is that `whitespace` is not 1 so it will keep going as long as `whitespace` is not 1. `whitespace` is updated in the loop and that is why

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that are causing this issue. The first is you are mutating the list as you iterate through it. This is the reason why it is not picking up on the whitespace on item 2 (index 0) of the list. You increment the index and pop the first item causing item 2 to become item 1 and then you check what is now item 2 (was item 3) which does not have a condition that terminates.

You also have no bound on `config_index` allowing it to go outside the list bounds.

This is better done with a `for` loop

```py
push_configs = ['  dns-server 8.8.8.8 ', ' ip dhcp pool WIRELESS', '  network 10.99.99.0 255.255.255.0', '  default-router 10.99.99.1 ', '  dns-server 8.8.8.8 ', '  ip dhcp pool HUMAN_RESOURCE ', '   network 10.88.88.0 255.255.255.0', '   default-router 10.88.88.1 ', '   dns-server 8.8.8.8 ']
for config in push_configs:
    white_space = len(config) - len(config.lstrip())
    if white_space == 1:
        break # breaks on element 2
    # do other stuff here

    print(config, white_space)
```

Comment: to op, `print config, white_space` as it seems you are on python 2

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are removing items from your list but still increasing your index. Do this instead:

```
push_configs = ['  dns-server 8.8.8.8 ', ' ip dhcp pool WIRELESS', '  network 10.99.99.0 255.255.255.0', '  default-router 10.99.99.1 ', '  dns-server 8.8.8.8 ', '  ip dhcp pool HUMAN_RESOURCE ', '   network 10.88.88.0 255.255.255.0', '   default-router 10.88.88.1 ', '   dns-server 8.8.8.8 ']

whitespace = len(push_configs[0]) - len(push_configs[0].lstrip())
while(whitespace != 1):
   print whitespace
   push_configs.pop(config_index)
   whitespace = len(push_configs[0]) - len(push_configs[0].lstrip())
   print whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

I see there are two problems: First that you pop and keep incrementing the index, second that there may not be any element in the list with only 1 whitespace. Correct me if I misunderstood the problem